# "(not set)" in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Since 1 mounth, I see many pages tagged "(not set)" in the navigation summary section.
[image]

If I look for global traffic evolution for this tag, it is alwas 0.
[image]

Where do this kind of tag can comme from ?

Comment: I would ask your question there : http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

By default GA's tracking code tracks pages by their URL in that report. But you can override this by passing a specific value to be reported in the _trackPageview() trigger.

So in order for "(not set)" to show up in that report, you must have code on your page that is passing that value to _trackPageview().

So you need to look at your GA code and look at the javascript that decides what to pass to _trackPageview() and look at the logic that is used to produce that "(not set)" value.

If I had to take a random guess, I would say you have javascript on the page that attempts to make virtual page names based off the URL and maybe "(not set)" is the default value that is used, for instance, if there is no directory path in the URL to build the virtual page name, or maybe it's based on some site category or something.  But that's just a random guess since I have no clue what your page code looks like or the intention behind it.

Comment: The only call to _trackPageview in my code looks like this :`if (code)
    tracker._trackPageview(code);
else
    tracker._trackPageview();`. So no way I track null, empty or undefined tags.

Comment: I also checked for "no set" string in my code, it does not comme from there.

Comment: Okay, well "(not set)" can also mean for entries the user went directly to your site, and for exits, they closed browser from that page.

Comment: If so, I have 2questions: 1- What is the difference between "28.91% Exits" and "10.82% (not set)" (see my screenshots). 2- Why do we see "(not set)" tags only since 1 month ?